# How to group duplicate data in a data set?

Tags: dataset

This is the data set I am working with. I Have two rows that repeat and I know how to delete them, but how can I group duplicate data in the data set so I can identify which rows or elements are duplicated in my dataset?

[image]

Here is the code of the data set:

```
Datas = Dataset@
  {
   <|"ID" -> 1, "Avg velocity" -> 20 "m/s", "Distance" -> 80 "m", 
    "Ball color" -> Red|>,
   <|"ID" -> 2, "Avg velocity" -> 26 "m/s", "Distance" -> 110 "m", 
    "Ball color" -> Blue|>,
   <|"ID" -> 3, "Avg velocity" -> 7 "m/s", "Distance" -> 10 "m", 
    "Ball color" -> Yellow|>,
   <|"ID" -> 4, "Avg velocity" -> 25 "m/s", "Distance" -> 20 "m", 
    "Ball color" -> Orange|>,
   <|"ID" -> 5, "Avg velocity" -> 3 "m/s", "Distance" -> 80 "m", 
    "Ball color" -> Purple|>,
   <|"ID" -> 5, "Avg velocity" -> 3 "m/s", "Distance" -> 80 "m", 
    "Ball color" -> Purple|>,
   <|"ID" -> 6, "Avg velocity" -> 1.4 "m/s", "Distance" -> 40 "m", 
    "Ball color" -> Gray|>,
   <|"ID" -> 7, "Avg velocity" -> 03 "m/s", "Distance" -> 90 "m", 
    "Ball color" -> Cyan|>,
   <|"ID" -> 8, "Avg velocity" -> 24 "m/s", "Distance" -> 50 "m", 
    "Ball color" -> White|>,
   <|"ID" -> 9, "Avg velocity" -> 22 "m/s", "Distance" -> 100 "m", 
    "Ball color" -> LightBlue|>,
   <|"ID" -> 10, "Avg velocity" -> 9 "m/s", "Distance" -> 80 "m", 
    "Ball color" -> LightMagenta|>,
   <|"ID" -> 11, "Avg velocity" -> 9.9 "m/s", "Distance" -> 70 "m", 
    "Ball color" -> Black|>,
   <|"ID" -> 11, "Avg velocity" -> 9.9 "m/s", "Distance" -> 70 "m", 
    "Ball color" -> Black|>
   }
```

Comment: `GroupBy[Datas, "ID"]`

Comment: Thanks, does ``GroupBy`` can also work with with rows in the case I have rows?

Comment: @LasDes you could post a relevant `Dataset` to help others better help you answer this!

Answer (score 2):

Just apply:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Datas]
```

[image]

If you want to find which elements are duplicated, then simply use @b4m2a1's solution:  `Groupby[Datas, "ID"]`.

Comment: From the first line in the question: "I Have two rows that repeat and _I know how to delete them_, but how can I group duplicate data in the data set so I can identify which rows or elements are duplicated in my dataset?"